# ARM Linux file empty after reboot

Tags: linux

I'm trying to open a file for rewriting. I then close the file, and reopen it for read to validate it was written OK. It is indeed as it should be. But, after I unplug the unit (ARM) and plug it again, I find that the file becomes empty. I also tried copying the file manually (with cp), and the same phenomenon reoccurs. 
here is some code:

```
string fileName = "/home/root/LogiTrackV2/InitialSetup.xml";                
ofstream theFile (fileName.c_str());
if (theFile.is_open())
{

   theFile.close();
}

theFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::trunc);

theFile << xmlOUT.c_str();
theFile.close();
```

As I mentioned after this the file exist and updated as it should. The problem is when I unplug the unit...

Comment: Are you sure that the file was actually flushed to persistent memory? Try `fsync` or `sync`.

Comment: Which ARM board do you use ? Do you know if you use a RAMFS ?

Comment: mount could give a clue if you're using a ram filesystem

Comment: @VivienG I am using ARM7

Comment: Did you use a precompiled Linux Kernel ?

Comment: Can you send us a link where you download it, may be the link of the seller of your board or reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is more complex than I thought in C++. There is no way in the standard library to force a POSIX `fsync` call on an `ofstream`. You can however use Boost.Iostreams with a `file_descriptor_sink` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file_descriptor.html) and do an `fsync` on the provided `fd` to force Linux into writing the file to disk.

Comment: fsync indeed did the job. Since it doesn't work with ofstream I modified the code to use file descriptor (open(...)). Just for knowledge sake, why when I didn't use  fsync, some times my code worked and on others it didn't?  Thanks!

Comment: This depends on Linux' IO scheduling. A simplistic scheduler could for example flush to disk every 15s or on a write-buffer overflow. The file data will stay in RAM until the next write cycle (even if you "flush" it on the C++ side of things) and will be served from there on read. If you disconnect the power before the data is written it is then lost.